# Seaborn Pariplot: how to move legend and set style

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn, pairplot

I'm trying to get a pairplot of my data using seaborn. I want to set the legend outside of the axes because my other plots might have upto 9 features which makes the plot too corwded.

My codes are:

```py
import seaborn as sns

my_data = data  
# a 80x4 dataframe. The last column key is label, and two different labels are in that column.

ax = sns.pairplot(my_data, hue="label")
```

The output has two problem:

1. The legend is overlapping with one of my scatter plot;
2. The word `label` is unwanted.
   [image: Plot 1]

I've tried to use `move_legend` according to the documentation [here](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.move_legend.html). I should be able to use `bbox_to_anchor` to set the exact location of my legend, so I added the following code:

```
sns.move_legend(ax, "lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1))  
# I want to place the legend in lower center and outside of the axes
```

but somehow my legend just disapeared.
[image: Plot 2]

When I do similar operation using `matplotlib`, the figure size is adjusted automatically, but the pairplot using seaborn is not changing at all which might be the reason. But I don't know how to fix it.

Update:
The data I use is uploaded to Google Drive and can be accessed via this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wuBs1WinP_fRMMzAo57Dhy4BmdgziO3O/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Your code is not reproducible. Maybe you could try to reproduce your issue using 3 columns from seaborn's penguins dataset? Also note that `sns.pairplot` does not return an `ax`, but a `PairGrid` (a figure consisting of a grid of subplots). You might try `sns.move_legend(g, "lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 0.01))` (with  `g = sns.pairgrid(...)`). To make some space, `plt.subplots_adjust(bottom=0.1)` or similar, might work (`plt.tight_layout()` doesn't work well for this kind of grids).

Comment: This issue is not reproducible. `sns.move_legend` works without issue using the given data. As can be seen in this [plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U8nfr.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`pairplot` already adds a legend outside the plot matrix. I do not know how you could get it inside of plot area. Probably there is something with plot figure size. I need more information about your code to detect the issue.

I've used test data in order to show some examples of plot legend locations.

```
# pip install matplotlib
# pip install seaborn

import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

penguins = sns.load_dataset("penguins")

g = sns.pairplot(penguins, hue="species")

handles = g._legend_data.values()
labels = g._legend_data.keys()
g.fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='upper center', ncol=1)
g.fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='lower center', ncol=3)
g.fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='upper left', ncol=3)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.92, bottom=0.08)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: So, this answer boils down to a "I cannot reproduce your problem" comment?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out to be a problem with Pycharm. After saving the figure to a file, the legends in both my code

```py
sns.move_legend(g, "lower center", bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, -0.1))
```

and @gremur's code

```py
g = sns.pairplot(penguins, hue="species")

handles = g._legend_data.values()
labels = g._legend_data.keys()
g.fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='upper center', ncol=1)
g.fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='lower center', ncol=3)
g.fig.legend(handles=handles, labels=labels, loc='upper left', ncol=3)
g.fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.92, bottom=0.08)
```

are working as expected.